# How to POST the readings from the sensor to the API

Tags: c++, json, post, arduino

The error is. `expected ')' before rainrate`. I need to POST the value of **rainrate** to my API, then reset the count of rainrate after POST. How can I do that? Thanks!

```
int httpResponseCode = http.POST("{\"amount\":"rainrate"}");
```

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <ESP8266HTTPClient.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>

const char* ssid = "*************";
const char* password = "*************";
//Your Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
const char* serverName = "************************";
const byte interruptPin = 4;
const int interval = 500;
volatile unsigned long tiptime = micros();
static float rainrate;
//float totalrainrate = 0.3;
void ICACHE_RAM_ATTR count();

// the following variables are unsigned longs because the time, measured in
// milliseconds, will quickly become a bigger number than can be stored in an int.
unsigned long lastTime = 0;
// Timer set to 10 minutes (600000)
//unsigned long timerDelay = 600000;
// Set timer to 5 seconds (5000)
unsigned long timerDelay = 15000;

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);

  WiFi.begin(ssid, password);
  Serial.println("Connecting");
  while(WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(".");
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.print("Connected to WiFi network with IP Address: ");
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP());
 
  Serial.println("Timer set to 5 seconds (timerDelay variable), it will take 5 seconds before publishing the first reading.");

    // Set up our digital pin as an interrupt
  pinMode(interruptPin, INPUT_PULLUP);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(interruptPin), count, RISING);
}

void loop() {

  wifi();
  rain();

}
void rain() {
unsigned long curtime = micros();
  
  // Make sure we don't record bounces
  if ((curtime - tiptime) < interval) {
    return;
  }

  // How long since the last tip?
  unsigned long tipcount = curtime - tiptime;
  tiptime = curtime;
  
  // Calculate mm/hr from period between cup tips

 Serial.print("Rain rate: ");
 Serial.print((float) rainrate * 0.1);
 Serial.println("mm/hr");
 delay (1000);
}

void count() {
  //rainrate = totalrainrate - 1;
  //rainrate - 1;
  rainrate++;
 
 
}

void wifi() {
  //Send an HTTP POST request every 10 minutes
  if ((millis() - lastTime) > timerDelay) {
    //Check WiFi connection status
    if(WiFi.status()== WL_CONNECTED){
      HTTPClient http;
      
      // Your Domain name with URL path or IP address with path
      http.begin(serverName);

      // Specify content-type header
      http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
      // Data to send with HTTP POST
      int httpResponseCode = http.POST("{\"amount\":"rainrate"}");

     
      Serial.print("HTTP Response code: ");
      Serial.println(httpResponseCode);
        
      // Free resources
      http.end();
    }
    else {
      Serial.println("WiFi Disconnected");
    }
    lastTime = millis();
  }
}
```

Comment: I won't ask if I know.

Answer (score 0):

You are attempting to send a string with double quotes but have not escaped all of the quotes inside the string passed to `POST()`.

This can be done with:

```
int httpResponseCode = http.POST("{\"amount\":\"rainrate\"}");
```

Your original string is terminated at the beginning of the text "rainrate". Hence the parser expects a closing `)` at this point.